# Showing that a linear operator on $\ell^1$ is unbounded

Tags: functional-analysis

I am struggling with proving the unboundedness of a linear operator on $\ell^1$:

Define the space $W := \{ a=\{a_k \}_k | \sum_k k |a_k| < \infty \}$, equipped with the $\ell^1$ norm. Define the operator $T: W \rightarrow \ell^1$ by $(Ta)_k = ka_k$. I need to show that $T$ is NOT bounded.
What I have done so far: I showed that the graph $\Gamma(T)$ of $T$ is closed. I have also shown that $W$ is a proper, dense subspace of $\ell^1$ ($W$ is not complete). But now I seem to have reached two contradictory conclusions:

**Attempt 1:**

$||T|| = \sup\limits_{||a||_1 = 1}{||Ta||} = \sup\limits_{||a||_1 = 1}{||\{ka_k\}_k||} = \sup\limits_{||a||_1 = 1}{\sum_k k |a_k|} < \infty$, by definition of $W$.

So doesn't this mean that $T$ is bounded?

**Attempt 2:**

Let $e_n := \{\delta_{kn}\}_k = \{0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0, ...\}$, where the $1$ occurs at the $k=n$ position of the sequence. Then we can easily show that $||e_n||=1$, and $e_n\in W$. Then we have $||Te_n|| = || \{k\delta_{kn}\}_k || = \sum_k k | \delta_{kn} | = n$.

But since this holds for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $||T|| = n$ implies that $||T|| = \infty$, so $T$ is unbounded.

Which is correct, if either? I am inclined to just trust my second attempt since this yields the desired result, but I cannot ignore my first attempt or see the flaw in my reasoning there. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt is the correct one, though saying "$\|T\| = n$" is not quite right, but changing it to $\geq n$ would work.

The reason your first attempt isn't correct is simply because, while each ${\sum_k k |a_k|}$ is finite, the $\sup\limits_{||a||_1 = 1}{\sum_k k |a_k|}$ might not be (and in this case isn't), simply think about $\sup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{n} = +\infty$ while each $n$ is finite for example.